# Bootstrap CSS Navigation Active class change onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a problem getting the active class to change when next page is clicked. I have tried numerous different variations of scripts that I found on here, but haven't had any luck getting any to work. My project is located here: [http://criminallawyerhuntsville.com/proof/](http://criminallawyerhuntsville.com/proof).

```
    <script>
            $('.navbar-right li').click(function(e) {
            $('.navbar-right li.active').removeClass('active');
            var $this = $(this);
            if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
                $this.addClass('active');
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    </script>
  </head>
      <body>
          <div id="wrapper">
              <header id="header" style="backface-visibility: hidden; transition: -webkit-transform 0.25s ease-in-out;">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                  <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Navbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                      </button>
                      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/robertsonlogo.png" height="50px"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Navbar">
                      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="domestic_violence.php">Domestic Violence</a></li>
                        <li><a href="drug.php">Drug Crime</a></li> 
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </nav>
            </header>
```

Comment: Wrap your script inside `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Comment: Your proof link doesn't work, but my guess is that you are actually clicking the link instead of the li so it is reloading the page meaning none of your changed classes will be present, and what pugazh said - run the code on doc ready

Comment: @Pete Try the link again

Answer (score 0):

Your using jQuery with no $(document).ready() ? change your code to the following for it to even trigger then check the console for errors if any.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.navbar-right li').click(function(e) {
        $('.navbar-right li.active').removeClass('active');
        var $this = $(this);
        if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
            $this.addClass('active');
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: That works as far as changing the active class but now when i click the links, it doesn't change the page just the active class changes

Comment: When i click the link in the navbar the active li changes but the page stays on index.php

Comment: @DamianSheldon you need to either change the class server side when the new page loads, or use ajax to load the new content if you are changing it client side

Answer (score 0):

If you use prevent default you want to prevent the anchor tag to work, so the click have to be on it
This example is if your active class is on the li and not the anchor:

```
$('.navbar-right li a').click(function(e) {
   $('.navbar-right li.active').removeClass('active');

   if (!$(this).parent().hasClass('active')) {
     $(this).parent().addClass('active');
   }
   e.preventDefault();
 });
```

as tried here: https://jsfiddle.net/xhgwjxku/